# The relation of W[1]-hard and Para-NP-hard

Tags: parameterized-complexity

Is it possible that a problem is both W[1]-hard and Para-NP-hard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible.

Take a parameterized problem $P_1$ that is W[1]-hard and a parameterized problem $P_2$ that is para-NP hard. Now consider the problem $P_3:=\{(0w,k)\mid (w,k)\in P_1\}\cup\{(1w,k)\mid (w,k)\in P_2\}$.
A reduction from $P_1$ to $P_3$ works by just prepending a $0$ to the first part of the input. It runs in polynomial time. It does not change the parameter. The output is in $P_3$ if and only if the input is in $P_1$. Hence, it is a parameterized reduction from $P_1$ to $P_3$. As $P_1$ is W[1]-hard, so is $P_3$.
In the same way we can prove that $P_3$ is para-NP-hard.

The above is a quite general approach to "being hard for two classes". In the present case, we can argue much simpler: W[1] is a subset of para-NP, so each para-NP-hard problem (e.g. graph colouring, parameterized by the number of colours) is also W[1]-hard.

The point is that "hard for a class" is open ended: It is preserved by making a problem even harder. This may not be what you had in mind. So let's consider a different question: Is it possible that a problem is both W[1]-complete and para-NP-complete (meaning that both classes coincide)? There, the answer is unknown. For all we know, W[1] may coincide with one of FPT or para-NP, with both, or with none. Settling the question is closely tied to P-vs-NP.